unable to update confirmationcode in wso2 IS(5.11) using scim 2.0
We are trying to update confirmationcode in wso2 using SCIM 2 rest API(WSO2 IS 5.11) but its giving 401 unauthorized below is the curl command
[
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://<host:port>/scim2/Users?filter=userName%20eq%20%22ssdev%40yopmail.com%22' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YXBwdXNlckBhcHBLmNvbTpBdXN0aW4xMjM=' \
--data-raw '{
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
    "Operations": [
      {
        "op": "replace",
        "value": {
          "confirmationcode": "fbcf6a17-daa6-4953-a1f7-f4ae7aef0578"
        }
      }
    ],
    "userName":"ssdev@yopmail.com"
  }'

]
Also we have tried the same in SCIM 1.0 rest API which is giving 200 ok response but confirmationcode is not getting updated in WSO2 IS. Below is the curl command
[
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://<host:port>/wso2/scim/Users/172660' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YXBwdXNlckBhcHBLmNvbTpBdXN0aW4xMjM=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "confirmationcode": "a5beb9cc-4d85-4710-8b0d-0b13d3829daf",
    "email":"ssdev@yopmail.com"
}'

]
Is there any way to update the confirmationcode in WSO2 IS using rest API?

What is the actual usecase that you are trying? SCIM APIs are for user's CRUD operations. Confirmation codes are inititaed due to approval flows etc. What is the usecase that you want to update the confirmation code?
